# Why Float conversion ignore zero's after decimal point?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I don't know why float data type ignores .00.

Like

```
165.00 = 165 ( It displays in this format after ignoring zero's)
165.65 = 165.65
```

I want to display if float length is less than 5, then add zero's at the end of the digit
like
165 then it'll display 165.00 ( i am using float data type)

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can give format in `ToString()` by specifing two zeros after the decimal point. You can read more about numeric formats [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
num.ToString(".00");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can format numeric values via `ToString()` Here is some example MSDN provided.

```
   double value;

 value = 123;
 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("00000"));
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:00000}", value));
 // Displays 00123 

 value = 1.2;
 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                   "{0:0.00}", value));
 // Displays 1.20

 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("00.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                 "{0:00.00}", value));
 // Displays 01.20

 CultureInfo daDK = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK");
 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("00.00", daDK)); 
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format(daDK, "{0:00.00}", value));
 // Displays 01,20 

 value = .56;
 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0.0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                 "{0:0.0}", value));
 // Displays 0.6 

 value = 1234567890;
 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0,0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));    
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                 "{0:0,0}", value));    
 // Displays 1,234,567,890      

 CultureInfo elGR = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("el-GR");
 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0,0", elGR));    
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(elGR, "{0:0,0}", value));   
 // Displays 1.234.567.890 

 value = 1234567890.123456;
 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0,0.0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));  
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                 "{0:0,0.0}", value));  
 // Displays 1,234,567,890.1   

 value = 1234.567890;
 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0,0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); 
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                 "{0:0,0.00}", value)); 
 // Displays 1,234.57
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. You can read more about numeric N format specifier [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#NFormatString).

```
float  someFloat= 165.00F;
Console.WriteLine(someFloat.ToString("N2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, It sounds like what you want is just a way to represent your `float` in a specific format.

I am sure you realize that `165.00 === 1.65`, so, after you do a:

```
float a = 165.00;
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString())
```

getting `165` is a valid (and expected) behaviour.

So, In order to allow you to get the format you want, You need to apply a [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#NFormatString) to your numer.
In your case:

```
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("N2"));
```